# Visual Studio Resource Editor ActiveX control ... could not be instantiated after I just added it with the resource editor?

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, activex, ocx, resource-editor

Trying to follow multiple tutorials on adding RDP client support to an MFC project and I can add the ActiveX control just fine, but when I close the dialog in the resource editor then try to open it back up, I always get:

> Microsoft Visual Studio
> The ActiveX control "Microsoft RDP Client Control - version 11" could not be instantiated.

I then have to manually edit the .rc file and remove the control it added from the dialog.   How do I stop it from doing this?

Two different tutorials can be found [here](https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=ba44f8d7-9619-4224-8889-083aa3a0d1a4#gsc.tab=0) and [here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/65123148481/)

Comment: *"How do I stop it from doing this?"* - What's *"it"* and *"doing this"*?

Comment: visual studio resource editor is "it" and "doing this" is giving the error message indicated (even after it was used to create the control).

Comment: Don't add the ActiveX control then. Though I'm having a feeling that you're looking for a solution to a different problem than the one you asked for.

Comment: But that's how you do it, add RDP client support on a dialog.   See tutorials linked.  I just can't get back in to a dialog that has the control on it.  But worked fine when creating it.

Comment: FWIW, MS is working on this.